# How do I make this relative layout without hard coding?

Tags: android, xml, button, textview, android-relativelayout

So I have 11 buttons and 1 TextView on this layout, it's goes like this:

```
:button: :button: :button:
:button: :button: :button:
:button: :button: :button:
:centered textview:
:button: :button: two of these fills width
```

Now I made it so that the gravity is centered, but what I want is the buttons to fill the screen with buttons not the background. Is there any way to do this with a relative layout and not hard coding the buttons?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tictactoe"
android:layout_width="fill_parent";
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3399CC"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/top_left"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/top_left"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/top_right"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/top"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_left"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/left"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bottom_left"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bottom"
        android:textSize="55dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bottom_left"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/click"
        android:textColor="#99FF00"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/result"
        android:text="@string/menu"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playagain"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/result"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/exit"
        android:text="@string/playAgain"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is achievable with just a RelativeLayout. Most likely you will need to use the `weight` tag which means linearlayout (possibly grid).

Comment: @anthropomo Ok, I changed my layout to using nested linearlayouts and using weights.